# magento 2 : resize image before upload on server

Tags: magento2, image-upload, image-resize

I want to upload images for custom module, so before upload image on media folder I want that resize image.
How can I set resize image before upload on media folder ?

Here is my code:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,

       
        array $data = []
         
        )
    {
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_logLoggerInterface = $loggerInterface;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
       $this->imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        
        parent::__construct($context);
         
         
    }

    
    
    public function execute()
    {   
         try {$files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('image');
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($files);die();
    
            foreach($files as $key => $value){
            $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
            $imageAdapter->open($value["tmp_name"]);
            $imageAdapter->constrainOnly(TRUE);        
            $imageAdapter->keepTransparency(TRUE);        
            $imageAdapter->keepFrame(FALSE);        
            $imageAdapter->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);        
            $imageAdapter->resize(100,100); 
             $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $imagepathfolder= 'test/';
            $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagepathfolder);
            $imageAdapter->save($destinationPath);
            
}echo "<pre>";print_r($result);die();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();die();
        }
            
        
        /* $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($printPath);
        return $resultJson; */
        }
```

I am getting error when I run above my code
**Warning: imagejpeg(C:/wamp64/www/magento234/pub/media/test): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp64\www\magento234\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php on line 208**

**What I want:**

I have created a custom module and I have set one custom form with some fields. In this form I have set file input type in the form and other input fields, so when customer filled up form with image by file input and click on submit button ,it called JavaScript method and trigger ajax and call controller method where I put my above code.When I receive form elements' values as a post method in controller that time I want that image as resize image before upload process of that image.

**Note**

I DO NOT WANT TO UPLOAD THAT IMAGE IN ORIGINAL SIZE AND RESIZE THAT IMAGE AND UPLOAD ON OTHER PATH. I WANT THAT IMAGE FIRST RESIZE THEN IT SHOULD UPLOAD ON SERVER

Comment: please provide us more information on what is the current output and what is expected. do you see exceptions?

Comment: @PhilippSander I have updated my question and mentioned error and what I want, please check it ,thank you

Comment: @NirajPatel what's the permissions on `C:/wamp64/www/magento234/pub/media/test` it looks like it's just a permissions issue.

Comment: @Haim when I used temp_name that time it throws error about permission but If I used by file name and it upload successfully It throws permission issue because it is getting temp path in temp_name variable. When you used my code and try you will get more idea

Comment: @niraj can you show the full error you're getting?

Comment: @Haim I already posted full errors which I am getting

Comment: When do you need this resized image to be created? is it with a cron? or is it each time a product is created? is it only for product or category as well?

Comment: @Herve Tribouilloy I am uploading images for my custom module form. I have created one form where I am uploading images using Ajax.

Comment: we are trying to help Niraj. It is obvious your bounty has many interests. However, your post is too vague at the moment. If you need an answer, you may want to describe more thoroughly (more details: when, what, ..) and no doubt you will have some answers

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy I have edited my question, please check 'what I want' section. Thank you

Comment: Yes I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 solutions, one that uses the uploader and then resizes. I understand you'd rather resize right away and therefore the solution below does exactly this. I have changed only 3 lines really so you were very close (I am quite impressed by your accuracy)

you can either install the module:
https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/contactwithavatar/src/master/

and reuse this code or the code below should be sufficient for you to modify your code

```
<?php
    
    namespace Mbs\ContactWithAvatar\Model;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
    
    class NirajPatelImageManipulator
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory
         */
        private $adapterFactory;
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem
         */
        private $filesystem;
        /**
         * @var DirectoryList
         */
        private $directoryList;
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        private $storeManager;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
            DirectoryList $directoryList,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        ) {
            $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
            $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
            $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        }
    
        public function resize($value, $fileName, $width = null, $height = null)
        {
            $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
            $imageAdapter->open($value["tmp_name"]);
            $imageAdapter->constrainOnly(TRUE);
            $imageAdapter->keepTransparency(TRUE);
            $imageAdapter->keepFrame(FALSE);
            $imageAdapter->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
            $imageAdapter->resize(100,100);
            $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $imagepathfolder= 'test' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($imagepathfolder);
            $imageAdapter->save($destinationPath . $fileName);
    
            $resizedURL = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA). $imagepathfolder .  $fileName;
            return $resizedURL;
        }
```

and I have allowed myself to return the ful url to see the image, this is something you may want to return in your ajax response

Comment: what you changed in the code ? I can not see any noticable changes. My code and your code are same. I put your code in my controller and it throws same error.

Comment: Could you please share your module with me ? Because it throws error permission issue in $value[‘temp_name’].

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to the module

Comment: Thank you genius thanks for your valuable time

Comment: as I said in my answer, that was a very good question. Really enjoyed it and more so when the bounty came my way, thank you @Niraj